# Send a kafka consumer record as json response from a resource and build again from json response

Tags: java, apache-kafka

How can I convert a kafka consumer record object into json string and send from a resource, and then on the client side take that json and construct a consumer record?

The application isn't using any spring dependencies currently, just jax-rs.

Comment: How about Avro?

Comment: do you know any sample code or good links that shows doing it with avro?

Comment: There are many example on how to use Avro with Kafka. Google is your friend.